# How to get filtered record from LINQ - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two list objects -

LIST1 -->

```
Cloumn1   Cloumn2
RI          1
OH          2
MI          3
```

LIST2 -->

```
Column1   Column2
RI          1
TX          2
NY          3
MI          3
OH          4
```

Now, I need to fetch the data from LIST2 when row is not matching in LIST1. like I am looking for following result -

```
TX   2
NY   3
OH   4
```

How can I achieve it through LINQ query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it would be in `VB.Net`, in `C#` it would be like this:

```
IList<MyObj> result = list2.Where(i2 => list1.All(i1 => i1.Column1 != i2.Column1 || i1.Column2 != i2.Column2)).ToList();
```

I beleive it would be something like this:

```
Dim result = From i2 In list2
             Where list1.All(Function(i1 As MyObj)
                             Return i1.Column1 <> i2.Column1 Or i1.Column2 <> i2.Column2
                             End Function)
             Select i2
```